# Delete Attachment file after being send

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, email-attachments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delete attachment file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857107/delete-attachment-file)

I am trying to delete a file automatically after it's being send with the following code:

```
        protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //  Inserting attachment to the email
                using (Attachment data = new Attachment("C:\\local\\vCardGenerator.Website\\" + "FirstName_LastName.vcf", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet))
            {

            //  add Send E-mail class
                SendvCard smtp = new SendvCard();

            //  Calls method to class
                smtp.MailvCard("anonymous@domain.com", "C:\\local\\vCardGenerator.Website" + "\\" + "FirstName_LastName" + ".vcf");
            }

            //  Status label + Delete file
            lblStatus.Text = "vCard Send to:" + " " + txtMail.Text;


//Delete file after being send as an attachment with the mail
            FileInfo DeleteFileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\\local\\vCardGenerator.Website" + "\\" + "FirstName_LastName" + ".vcf");
            if (DeleteFileInfo.Exists)
                File.Delete("C:\\local\\vCardGenerator.Website" + "\\" + "FirstName_LastName" + ".vcf");
```

Debugging without the 'auto delete' runs perfectly smooth, it even sends the email with the attachment, but when I try to delete the attachment after it's being send I get the following error pop-up:

> The process cannot access the file. (~\"Path") because it is being used by
>   another process.

Is there anyone that knows why this error may occur?
Do I need to Dispose the file first?

Willing to provide any other/more information if needed.
Thanks in Advance,

Comment: How quickly are you trying to do this?  Also, provide a little more of the code around these lines.

Comment: I see no clear answer on that thread. Since the original poster didn't provide any code

Comment: On a side note, I suggest looking at [Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx).

Comment: Do you actually need to use a temporary file? Can't you just handle the content in memory?

Answer (score 4):

If you dispose the the mail message it will close resources within it and unlock the files

Answer (score 1):

`SendvCard` isn't part of the .NET Framework so I can't tell you for sure, however, I would hazard a guess at it internally creating a `MailMessage` object which will lock down the attachment until it's disposed. Also it looks as though you are unnecessarily creating a new `Attachment` object because as far as I can see, it doesn't get used.

What you need to do is dispose of your `smtp` object *before* you try to delete the attachment, so if `SendvCard` implements `IDisposable` your code could look something like:

```
using (var smtp = new SendvCard())
{
    //  Calls method to class
    smtp.MailvCard("anonymous@domain.com", "C:\\local\\vCardGenerator.Website" + "\\" + "FirstName_LastName" + ".vcf");

}

//  Status label + Delete file
lblStatus.Text = "vCard Send to:" + " " + txtMail.Text;

//Delete file after being send as an attachment with the mail
FileInfo DeleteFileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\\local\\vCardGenerator.Website" + "\\" + "FirstName_LastName" + ".vcf");
if (DeleteFileInfo.Exists)
    File.Delete("C:\\local\\vCardGenerator.Website" + "\\" + "FirstName_LastName" + ".vcf");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used one of the Attachment constructors which doesn't require a file to start with.
I wrote to a MemoryStream, rewinded it and then provided that to the Attachment.

After that I received another error, which will be for a new thread.

I thank everybody for their help and answers even though I didn't need them.

Comment: Do you even need the `Attachment` instance at all though? You don't use it anywhere in your code? It looks as though `SendvCard` takes an attachment string as a parameter (I may be wrong).